# How can I change the state of another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

**CODE:**

```
var React = require('react');
var RecipeBox = require('./RecipeBox.jsx');
var AddRecipe = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function () {
         RecipeBox.setState({
             adding: false
         });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="popUp">
                <button className = "btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick}>X</button>
                <h2>Add a Recipe</h2>
                <form>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <input></input>
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AddRecipe;
```

---

**SITUATION:**

The solution above does not work. I would like to set `adding` to `false` for the RecipeBox Component from the AddRecipe Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, see here [how to communicate between components](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/).
You have to use parents / children component to do so, or use a lib like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/)

Comment: Also see this article https://www.ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly change child component state from parent as that is not preferred React way. You can pass `adding` as a `prop` to `RecipeBox` component and have `componentWillReceiveProps` method inside `RecipeBox` components which sets the `RecipeBox` state.

If for some reason really need to do it (directly), you can add a `ref` on the `RecipeBox` component like this:

```
<RecipeBox ref={(ref) => this.recipeBox = ref} adding={this.state.adding}/>
```

And than you can call `this.recipeBox.setState({...})` from `AddRecipe` component. But remember this is not preferred react way.

Answer (score -1):

**If AddRecipe has no relationship to RecipeBox**

Then you can use the observer pattern like so, using a small library like [microevent](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/microevent.js):

In some module called events.js for example:

```
var MicroEvent = require('./microevent.js');
module.exports = new Ticker();
```

In RecipeBox's file:

```
var ticker = require('./events.js');

var RecipeBox = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.addingHandler = () => this.setState({ adding: false });
    ticker.bind('adding', this.addingHandler);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    ticker.unbind('adding', this.addingHandler);
  }

});
```

In AddRecipe's file:

```
var React = require('react');
var RecipeBox = require('./RecipeBox.jsx');
var ticker = require('./events.js');

var AddRecipe = React.createClass({
    onAdd: function() {
      ticker.trigger('adding');
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="popUp">
                <button className = "btn btn-danger" onClick={this.onAdd}>X</button>
                <h2>Add a Recipe</h2>
                <form>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <input></input>
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AddRecipe;
```

**If RecipeBox is a child of AddRecipe**

You should not try to change the state of RecipeBox this way. If `RecipeBox` is a child component of `AddRecipe` then you should pass a prop down to it instead:

```
var React = require('react');
var RecipeBox = require('./RecipeBox.jsx');
var AddRecipe = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function () {
         // you should only change your own state, see how
         // we set 'adding' on RecipeBox on one of the last
         // lines of render instead
         this.setState({
             adding: false
         });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="popUp">
                <button className = "btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClick}>X</button>
                <h2>Add a Recipe</h2>
                <form>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <input></input>
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <RecipeBox adding={this.state.adding}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AddRecipe;
```

**If AddRecipe is a child of RecipeBox**

If `RecipeBox` is instead the parent of `AddRecipe` then you should propagate `adding: false` up to `RecipeBox` like so:

```
var RecipeBox = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return <AddRecipe onAdd={this.onAdd.bind(this}/>;
  }

  onAdd: function() {
    this.setState({ adding: false });
  }

});

var React = require('react');
var RecipeBox = require('./RecipeBox.jsx');
var AddRecipe = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="popUp">
                <button className = "btn btn-danger" onClick={this.props.onAdd}>X</button>
                <h2>Add a Recipe</h2>
                <form>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <input></input>
                    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
                    <textarea></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AddRecipe;
```

Comment: Again you cannot access the onAdd function of recipeBox as a prop inside the AddRecipe compoent as they dont share a parent-child relationship

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri how do you know they don't when he hasn't said so?
 Regardless, I'll also add an example supporting any to any communication.

Comment: See his comment on your answer

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri his edited post at this moment in time does not indicate the relationship between the two Components. I stand by my answer given the current information provided in the question.